# Установка разных SSL сертификатов для разных сайтов на IIS

Tags: .net, asp.net, ssl, iis, windows-server-2012

Есть Windows Server 2012 R2, на нем IIS 8.
На сервере размещается 2 web приложения и в IIS установлено 2 SSL сертификата.

Так вот пока SSL использовался только на одном сайте - все было ок, а когда попытался установить на второй, он говорит, что надо установить данный сертификат для всех сайтов. А это не подходит для меня, поскольку сертификаты для разных доменов.

Сертификаты установлены c Certificate Store = WebHosting

[image: Вот сообщение, которое появляется]

Вообще возможно устанавливать различные сертификаты для различных сайтов внутри одного IIS? Если да (что было бы логично), то подскажите, пожалуйста, как

Comment: А Вы используете Server Name Indication (SNI)?

Comment: Нет, не использовал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попытаться использовать технологию SNI (SSL Host Header). Server Name Indication (SNI) позволяет множеству SSL-сайтов использовать один и тот же IP-адрес.

Подробнее про SNI на википедии - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication

К сожалению, SNI не поддерживается в старых браузерах (типа IE6).

Посмотрите также - [IIS 8.0 Server Name Indication (SNI): SSL Scalability](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-server-name-indication-sni-ssl-scalability)

Comment: А при работе с API все корректно будет работать? То есть у меня там же висит еще и API для сервиса и я хотел бы, чтобы все запросы к нему были также через https

Comment: Проблем быть не должно.

Answer (score 0):

Только что столкнулся с такой же проблемой, но решилось просто, поставил галочку `require server name indication` в настройках `bindings` (после этого запрос на `reassign` сертификата не появился)
Единственное что в DNS были прописаны алиасы всех сайтов на этом IIS.